# How to style Angular Material select drop down overlay

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material2

I have an angular component called currency-selector which has its own css file that looks like this:

```
.currency-select {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 80px;
    z-index: 1000000;
    color: #DD642A;
    font-size: 17px;
    padding-right: 16px;
    width: 130px;
}

.mat-form-field {
    display: block;
}
```

This works exactly as expected for the selector until it is clicked and the drop down happens. The html is as follows:

```
<div class="currency-select">
  <mat-form-field *ngIf=loaded>
    <mat-select [formControl]="currencyForm" placeholder="Select Currency">
      <select-search (search)="filterCurrencyOptions($event)" #selectSearch (keydown)="$event.stopPropagation()" >
      </select-search>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let currency of filteredCurrencies" [value]="currency.counter_currency_code" (click)="updateCurrency()">
          <flag-icon country="{{ (currency.counter_currency_iso_2 || '').toLowerCase() }}"></flag-icon>  {{currency.counter_currency_code}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

When I click on the currency select, the drop down doesn't appear how I want it to appear and I can't seem to add anything in the currency-select.component.html file to alter it, instead it seems to take the styling from a different div tag, "cdk-overlay-container".

Can anyone advise as to how I can write the css for this in the currency-select css file? I've tried using !important but this isn't working eithher.

Comment: can you share a working code, so that we can replicate/work on the issue. Like on stackblitz or similar platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To style the drop down overlay add a class to it using the `mat-select` input `panelClass`.

```html
<mat-select panelClass="myPanel">
```

Then use `::ng-deep`:

```css
::ng-deep .myPanel.mat-select-panel {
  background-color: darkslategray;
}
```

Or disable ViewEncapsulation for the component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'select-panel-class-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-panel-class-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['select-panel-class-example.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
```

```css
.myPanel.mat-select-panel {
  background-color: darkslategray;
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k4pxc1

Answer (score 2):

try using **ng-deep**

```
::ng-deep .your-class-name {
  ...
}
```

PS: ng-deep will get deprecated in further versions. W3C didn't defined a 'replacement' for it yet.

**Answer Update (07-07-2021)**: If you don't want to use ng-deep (deprecated), then use ViewEncapsulation.None: angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep